# Estimate the variance of a model using only the test score

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, variance, computational-statistics

This class on Coursera from [Andrew Ng. Class on Learning Curve](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/lecture/Kont7/learning-curves) shows that high variance could be inferred as a high gap between the training and test score. However, I was wondering if we can get a sense of high variance in a model in other ways. For example, if we use multiple test sets (using cross-validation) and then check the range of the test scores among them.

Answer (score 0):

By "high variance" I think you mean predictive or classification accuracy.

In regression analysis, estimating discrepancies between training and testing samples if called "shrinkage" and there are methods for estimation of shrinkage that might be applicable or interesting.

Regarding multiple test sets, in ML and elsewhere, people use K-fold crossvalidation where K is the number of groups. Training is performed K times. On round 1, group 1 is reserved for testing and the remaining K-1 groups are combined for training. On round 2, the second group is reserved and all the rest are used for training, etc. This provides K estimates of the accuracy of the model. The logical conclusion of this is leave-one-out crossvalidation (LOOCV) where K=N and each case is predicted/classified using the remaining N-1 other cases in the dataset. I think you could infer how robust your model predicts are by the variation across groups.

FWIW (because it's probably at least somewhat dependent on the application and the methodology) I investigated LOOCV as a remedy for small samples (using a particular type of model).  That is, if you don't have enough data to split into testing and training samples, would LOOCV allow you to crossvalidate efficiently? I found it very limited. First, there is a small negative bias, meaning that the crossvalidated "accuracy" is always a bit too low (I'm not enough of a mathematician to say why, but empirically it was obvious). Second, it was only useful in a narrow range of dataset sizes. In my case, around N=200. With fewer cases, all estimates were hopelessly inaccurate. By the time you have N=400 cases, it was better to simply divide the sample into testing and training halves (because of the negative bias).